# Python Numpy.ndarray.shape limit

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a matrix with Numpy in Python with the following code:

```
import numpy

result=numpy.zeros((20,20,20,30,30,30))

numpy.save('result',result)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "numpy_memoryerror.py",
line 5, in <module>
    result=numpy.zeros((20,20,20,30,30,30))
MemoryError
```

If I use smaller dimensions like these:

```
result=numpy.ones((10,10,10,20,20,20))
```

then the code works.

Can somebody tell me the limit of the shape tuple?

Comment: I try it on my computer, and it generate a .npy file of size 1.60 GB (1,728,000,096 bytes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not a fundamental limit of the shape tuple, its that you don't have enough memory (RAM) on your system, hence the `MemoryError`.

Again 20*20*20*30*30*30 is 216 million 64-bit (8 byte) floats or a little more than 1.6 GB of RAM.  So do you have 1.6 GB of RAM free while running the script at that point?  (Don't forget to all the RAM used by python, the OS, other running programs, etc.).  If you are in linux/unix you can see how much free memory by typing `free -m` from the command prompt.  In windows you can see free memory by going to the task manager.  Furthermore, some OSes limit the amount of memory that a single process (like python) can allocate; e.g., 32-bit windows only gives 2 GB of address space per process).

Compare that to 20*20*20*10*10*10, which is only ~0.06 GB (or just 27 times less memory).

If you don't need 8-byte floats, you could do

```
numpy.zeros(20,20,20,30,30,30, dtype='float32')
```

which would halve your memory footprint by using single-precision (32-bit) floats.  By default numpy uses dtype='float64'.

Roughly speaking a 32-bit float has 8 digits of accuracy, a 64-bit float has 16 digits of accuracy.  Meaning that 1+1e-8 appears as just 1 for 32-bit floats, and 1+1e-16 appears as 1 for 64-bit floats, but 1+1e-15 appears as 1.000000000000001 with 64-bit floats, but not 32-bit floats.

Comment: I tried it with dtype='float32', and it works, creating a file of around 860mb's. But, I run Win 7 64 bit, and I have 4 GB of ram, from which around 2.2 GB are available. Btw, there is a swapping (paging) of ram mechanism, that deals with processes that need more ram. In this case, it doesn't work.

Comment: @makmiler: Please note that for `numpy` arrays you need to have contiguous memory. Even if  you have plenty of memory to consume, it won't necessarily be contiguous in such big chunks as needed. Thanks

Comment: @eat: The memory that is reported as "available" by Windows is pageable, so it can be paged to a single continuous block.

Comment: @Sven: Are you sure?  E.g., matlab's documentation (which also requires contiguous block of RAM for arrays) reports fragmentation of memory for Out of Memory errors.  See:  http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1100/1106.html

Comment: @Sven: Good point, but firstly I'll like the OP to describe more detailed manner his environment, before making any final judgement. AFAIU, even with 64-bit Windows but user-mode virtual address space for 32-bit process (limiting it only to 2 GB) such fragmentation may emerge. Thanks